# Unable to set grails_remember_me cookie to use secure cookie

Tags: grails, spring-security

Referring to the documentation here:
https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/authentication.html#rememberMeCookie

I'm unable to get grails_remember_me to use secure cookie even though I've set it accordingly in Config.groovy:

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.useSecureCookie = true

Am I missing something here?